Voting for new TNB room owners 2024
The Nineteenth Byte is getting new room owners. You've had a week (and one hour) for nominations, and now it's time to vote. In alphabetical order, here are the nominees:

att
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here
Ginger
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here
Redz
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here
Seggan
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here
The Empty String Photographer
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here
Themoonisacheese
chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination | vote here

Each candidate has a community wiki answer below. You may vote on as many as you want, and the candidates are welcome to vote as well, including for (or against) themselves.
Voting will close in a week (1:00UTC, Tuesday 19th of November). At the end of the election, any candidates who recieve 10 or more upvotes, and at least three times as many upvotes as downvotes, will be added as room owners subject to approval by the existing moderators / ROs.
Best of luck to all candidates!
Important note: serial voting detection applies to meta as well. If you vote for several candidates within a short span of time, your votes may be automatically cancelled. Make sure you check back before the voting period closes to make sure your votes went through.

Ginger

chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination
Chat user since 2021-12-02.
447 messages this week. 171 messages last week. 367 messages per week.

Seggan

chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination
Chat user since 2021-10-04.
15 messages this week. 47 messages last week. 81 messages per week.

att


chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination

Chat user since 2018-12-15.
31 messages this week. 46 messages last week. 32 messages per week.

Redz

chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination
Chat user since 2022-12-23.
0 messages this week. 0 messages last week. 23 messages per week.

Themoonisacheese

chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination
Chat user since 2024-06-05.
34 messages this week. 109 messages last week. 86 messages per week.

The Empty String Photographer

chat profile | main profile | meta profile | nomination
Chat user since 2022-02-15.
146 messages this week. 212 messages last week. 172 messages per week.
